# Can SharePoint 2013 extract metadata from a PDF file during upload and fill columns with it?

Tags: file-upload, metadata, file-metadata

We are uploading a lot of PDF files to our SharePoint Sites and it is quite a lot of work to then add the metadata of those files, although many of them are already contained in the PDF file or are somehow coded in the filename.

So I wonder

- how is it possible to let SharePoint extract the metadata from the PDF file?
- is there a kind of metadata fields in the PDF format (comparable to the "doucment properties in Microsoft Office documents) which can easily be filled and read out? (The PDF Documents are created with `FrameMaker` and/or `Adobe Acrobat`)

Comment: Related post: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/d2ee01/extract-metadata-of-a-pdf-file-in-sharepoint-2013-document-l/